# What is the difference between using transistors and op-amps in pre-amplifiers?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, circuit-design, audio, preamp

What is the difference between using transistors and op-amps in the design of audio preamps? What are the advantages and disadvantages of using each?

Based on my research, using op-amps is better as it helps in utilizing fewer components in the circuit, provides more gain, and helps in avoiding biasing and stabilizing components.

I would be grateful if any books are mentioned that may be helpful in learning the design of audio amplifiers.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site :-) This appears to be a homework question with no effort shown or any attempts made by yourself. It is essentially asking for free tuition. It's a Q&A site, rather than discussion forum, and can't be a personal tutorial service, which is effectively what you're asking for. Hope you can see that. Please edit your question and show all your own workings and findings.

Comment: OPAMPs are made out of transistors...

Comment: @TonyM Thanks for the warm welcome. Fortunately, it is not a homework but it is me trying to learn a new thing (audio amplifiers). I could not see it honestly but thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: @Sayed For applications where both might solve the same problem, transistors have died and gone to heaven. Opamps rule the roost now. In audio, the place for transistors are two-fold: in the pre-amplifier stage (for example, using a JFET or BJT do have separate places, given careful design, where certain discretes are superior in accommodating specific transducers) and in the output transducer stage (speaker) where the opamp can't manage the required dissipation and discrete parts are needed. But there are audio ICs (TDA8551 is a good example) that leave only the pre-amp stage to worry over.

Comment: @Sayed Dr. Philip Hobbs (with whom I worked together for a few years) has written an excellent book called *"Building Electro-Optical Systems"*, where he discusses (and laments the loss of) some excellent discrete transistors that are no longer available, today, and outperform anything you can get today, as well. That said, there are some transistors available today that are pretty good. But we've lost a few gems over the years due to the fact that the market for them is too small to sustain their continued production. That's life in the big city, so to speak.

Comment: Transistors are like assembly or C, while op amps are more like high level languages: easier to use, more polished, almost ideal, but with larger overheads, cost, supply requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the answer to this question a bit disappointing.

There are two reasons to use transistors:

1. Less noise.
2. Because we can.

For (1), transistors can be selected with very low input noise, in terms of voltage or current noise, or generally noise figure.  Which one is optimized depends on the source being amplified, the frequency range, etc.

Very basically, an op-amp is composed of many transistors, so will always have more noise than a single transistor of similar ratings.

The other factor is, a single (discrete component) transistor can have larger geometry than fits inside an IC.  Big transistors (or effectively many small ones in parallel) have lower noise by sheer statistics alone, if nothing else.  There are many phenomena that generate noise in semiconductors, so you can't just toss any transistor at a problem and expect low noise, but low-noise parts can be found by testing and selection.

This is the more technically interesting aspect of the answer.

For (2), you will find there is a tremendous amount of tradition *(and superstition)* in audio communities.

From a strictly electrical standpoint, audio is a very simple problem to solve: the signal levels are fairly large (say, 100s µV, even for very poor sensitivity microphones and such), signal-to-noise ratios are modest (systems typically offer > 80 dB i.e. 16-bit digital quality or better), and ears can hear only a bit better than them in the best of conditions<sup>[1]</sup>, let alone others (for simultaneous signals, the SNR is more like 20 dB).

This means that, to produce an effective amplifier design, very little actual design is required.

In contrast, the community ranges from mildly interested in specifications [other than sheer power], to outright distrust in the scientific process itself.  I don't at all mean this pejoratively: there have indeed been multiple attempts through the years to test hi-fi listeners' ability to hear things (like telling two well-spec'd amplifiers apart).  There are some circles where double-blind testing is banned outright.

Meanwhile, the community thrives on novelty.  A new and interesting amplifier design will be more popular than retreading the same old design a hundred times, regardless how well the old design performs, or how poorly the new.  (I suppose that's descriptive of communities in general, really.)  So you see the promulgation of a great many designs, that are often quite terribly compromised from a technical standpoint, but which remain functional enough to pass as an amplifier as such.

This may be a rather cynical reading of things, of course; it is tinted by my cynical worldview.  On a less cynical note, it is nice to have fun with these designs — there is value in exploring nearly every possible permutation and type of transistor circuit.  Maybe still not well applied (audio is a very limited subset of all possible electronics that could benefit from such explorations), but that's fine, it's just an amusement after all.

Anyway, the other aspect is that, hi-fi audio often overlaps with high-art, in terms of customers/clients, prestige and presentation.  Physical design ranges from retro-classic to industrial chic to avant-garde.  This sometimes bleeds into the electrical design aspects as well.  Needless to say, more than ample budgets are available for some highly cost-inefficient designs: both in terms of number and type of components, and their power consumption (indeed, some see it as a virtue that an amplifier weighs a lot and outputs a mere fraction of the total power it consumes).

Mind, both aspects are independent: a $10,000 amplifier is no guarantee of $10,000-quality electronic design.  I've heard some contain bog-standard circuitry, of poor construction at that (safety hazard!).

This is the less technically interesting aspect of the answer, but may itself be interesting in a more psychological/sociological aspect.

---

So, this is all to say — beware what you see on the internet, as what you find is completely unfiltered, sampling from a wide range of areas: from genuine commercial designs, to random schematics people have slapped together.  There are some reasons to do it that way, but it's up to you to determine if they're doing it because they have to, or because they *want* to.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Minimum hearing limits are around 0 to -10 dBa (A-weighted acoustic decibels), at which levels you can hear the blood flow in your ears, the twitching of your facial muscles, and the creaking of your joints.  You might also start hallucinating: some have described such quiet chambers as a little "maddening".  The maximum is around 120 dBa, at which point ears themselves fail to work so well (mechanical limits), and damage occurs quickly (minutes to hours of exposure).  By "a bit better", I mean that, even in a quiet location, you're likely in the ~20 dBa ambient range, and even a powerful audio system will only be pushing a bit over 100 dBa at levels that begin to be uncomfortable.  Also, I'm stretching the meaning of "a bit" by a, er.. by a bit, since another 20 or 30 dB isn't exactly negligible, just that it's a much smaller part of the overall total (i.e., what's the difference between 90 and 120 dB when you can only use 80 to 20 dB of the range anyway?).